# How to define product of subsheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let X be a scheme. If $\mathcal F$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal O_ X$ module. IF $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ are two $\mathcal O_X$ submodules of $\mathcal F$. Then what is $\mathcal GH$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean to ask about $\mathscr{G}\mathscr{H}$; this doesn't make sense in general. For a general sheaf of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules there is no way to multiply sections.

There are some contexts where it does make sense, and it is defined as the sheaf image of some morphism. For example, if $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{O}_X$, so $\mathscr{G}$ and $\mathscr{H}$ are ideal sheaves, then $\mathscr{G}\mathscr{H}$ is (by definition) the sheaf image of the natural ``multiplication morphism" $\mathscr{G}\otimes_{\mathscr{O}_X}\mathscr{G}\rightarrow\mathscr{O}_X$. More generally, if $\mathscr{G}$ is an ideal sheaf and $\mathscr{H}$ a sheaf of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules, then $\mathscr{G}\mathscr{H}$ is the image of the morphism $\mathscr{G}\otimes_{\mathscr{O}_X}\mathscr{H}\rightarrow\mathscr{H}$ given by (restricting) the $\mathscr{O}_X$-module structure on $\mathscr{G}$.

Comment: @ Keenan: Or in general if $\mathcal F$ is an sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$ algebra, then we can define $\mathcal GH$ in a similar way. Am I right?

Comment: Dear @Susobhan, Yes, that's right. Note this has nothing to do with schemes. These are constructions with sheaves, and make sense in great generality.

Comment: Dear keenan: Might be a silly question, but can you please explain in brief what is that multiplication morphism  $ \mathcal G \otimes_{\mathcal O_X}$ $ \mathcal H$ $ \rightarrow \mathcal F$ in my context.

Comment: What is your context? When $\mathscr{F}$ is an $\mathscr{O}_X$-algebra and $\mathscr{G}$ and $\mathscr{H}$ are $\mathscr{O}_X$-submodules? Because $\mathscr{F}$ is an $\mathscr{O}_X$-algebra you have a map $\mathscr{F}\times\mathscr{F}\rightarrow\mathscr{F}$ which is $\mathscr{O}_X$-bilinear. Restrict this to the $\mathscr{O}_X$-submodule $\mathscr{G}\times\mathscr{H}$. Now invoke the universal property of the tensor product to get an $\mathscr{O}_X$-linear map $\mathscr{G}\otimes_{\mathscr{O}_X}\mathscr{H}\rightarrow\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: Yes, that is the context i wanted. Thanx for the help.